# Retrieving a value in a function in Node.js

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm struggling with callbacks in Node.js. I simply want playerNumber to be set to the number of players in my collection of Players. The console.log works, but I can't get the variable out of the function and into the playerNumber variable.

And if there's a simpler way get this value for use in the rest of my backend code, I'm all ears. I'm clearly new at Node.js, but the code always seems more involved than I'm expecting.

Thanks in advance!

```
var playerNumber = function countPlayers(callback){
    Player.count(function(err, numOfDocs) {
        console.log('I have '+numOfDocs+' documents in my collection');
        callback(err, numOfDocs);
    });
}
```

Comment: what are you doing in the callback?

Comment: This function looks like it is structured correctly with your callback.  To help further, we need to see the calling code that supplies the callback as that is likely where your issue is.

Comment: As for a simpler way to do this, what is `Player.count()`?  Is that part of some database?  It is generally simpler to use Promise interfaces on a database so that might be a simpler way to code this than using plain callbacks.

Comment: We can't help you here when you are non-responsive to questions.  This is NOT like some online forum where you post and come back the next day.  If you aren't around after posting when people are asking clarifying questions, your question will get downvoted or closed.  To get a good, fast answer without getting your question closed or downvoted, you must hang around after posting, check back regularly and be responsive to questions asked.  At least for the next hour after posting.  Plus, the first hour after posting is your best chance to get an answer.  If you're not here, you can miss that.

Comment: Yes, Player.count() is intended to count the number of current records in the Players collection. This is so I can later add a new record with a player number field of playerNumber + 1, essentially. So if there are 4 current players, the new player record to be created by the client and saved to the database will be player number 5. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably async, and it's a typical first-timer experience to want to "get back to normal" on the call chain on the way back from async call.  This can't be done, but it's not so bad to live with it. Here's how...

- Step 1: Promises are better than callbacks. I'll leave the long story
  to others.
- Step 2: Callbacks can be made into promises

In the OP case...

```
// The promise constructor takes a function that has two functions as params
// one to call on success, and one to call on error.  Instead of a callback
// call the 'resolve' param with the data and the 'reject' param with any error
// mark the function 'async' so callers know it can be 'await'-ed
const playerNumber = async function countPlayers() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Player.count(function(err, numOfDocs) {
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(numOfDocs);
    });
  });  
}
```

- Step 3: Yes, the callers must deal with this, and the callers of the callers, and so on.  It's not so bad.

In the OP case (in the most modern syntax)...

```
// this has to be async because it 'awaits' the first function
// think of await as stopping serial execution until the async function finishes
// (it's not that at all, but that's an okay starting simplification)
async function printPlayerCount() {
  const count = await playerNumber();
  console.log(count);
}

// as long as we're calling something async (something that must be awaited)
// we mark the function as async
async function printPlayerCountAndPrintSomethingElse() {
  await printPlayerCount();
  console.log('do something else');
}
```

- Step 4: Enjoy it, and do some further study. It's actually great that we can do such a complex thing so simply. Here's good reading to start with: [MDN on Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Thank you! I will dig into the Promises documentation and take that path. Oddly, Visual Studio is marking async as an unexpected keyword for me. It must be an extension I'm using?

Comment: I added "function" after "async" and perhaps that fixed my syntax problem. I'm not quite there yet. When I console.log printPlayerCount() I get "[Object Promise]". "count" is correctly resolving as the number I need, but I can't seem to get it returned later in my route.

Comment: @SleepyWakes - you're right to add function, my bad. And having the promise means you're close.  Inside a function, just await that promise.  `let result = await theObjectPromiseThing`.  At the top level, use `theObjectPromiseThing.then(result => console.log(result))`